# Neo4j: How to query in a breadth first search of nodes in a graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, breadth-first-search

I have got a graph model in neo4j with only one relationship as below:

```
(node1)-[:CONNECTS]->(node2)
```

Have tried the following query but it will give me bi-directional results:

```
MATCH (n:Label1)-[r:CONNECTS*1..]-(m) 
WHERE n.name = 'startNodeString' 
RETURN n,r,m
```

Below query will only return the first level of child nodes for given root node:

```
MATCH (cs:Label1)-[r:CONNECTS*]->(es:Label2)
WHERE cs.property = 'startNodeString'
RETURN cs,es,r
```

I would like to capture starting from root node going through each child node and recursively each child node till the depth of each level i.e. 'n' level.

Appreciate your help with cypher query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/) for this, specifically [path expander](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/path-expander/).

Here's an example of use:

```sql
MATCH (cs:Label1)
WHERE cs.property = 'startNodeString'
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(cs,{relationshipFilter:"CONNECTS>",maxLevel:3,uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL"}) YIELD path
WITH cs, RELATIONSHIPS(path) as r, LAST(NODES(path)) as es
WHERE es:Label2
RETURN cs,es,r
```

All path expander calls default to using bfs. `NODE_GLOBAL` uniqueness means nodes are only ever traversed once. You can set `maxLevel` to whatever depth limit you want, or omit it completely.

Comment: Unable to call apoc procedure after installing it under $NEO4J_HOME/plugins and restarted server; i get following error from shell>neo4j-sh (?)$ CALL dbms.procedures()
> Unknown command 'call'

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you running? Version 3.0 and up should support the CALL keyword and user created procedures. Better to use version 3.1.x though.

Comment: Now, I'm working on MacOS with version 3.1.1; build snapshot from latest code and copied it to plugins directory: /Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/; also tried copying jar to dir: $NEO4J_HOME/plugins
I get following error while starting server:
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6975bc23' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

Comment: Messages from log file:
WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseConnection` from plugin jar `/Applications/Neo4j%20Community%20Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.5-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/document/Document
2017-02-02 16:43:00.947+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseManager` from plugin jar `/Applications/Neo4j%20Community%20Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.5-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/env/CouchbaseEnvironment

Comment: You're using the wrong APOC snapshot. APOC is maintaining separate releases for versions 3.0.x and 3.1.x, and their latest release was one on the 3.0.x line, so the latest release link takes you here. You need the latest on the 3.1.x line. Check the releases link on their release page, then scroll down until you see the latest 3.1.x release and use that one instead.

Comment: I was able to call the procedure with the right version this time. Thanks for the help. After executing query mentioned above, it will still return me the only first level of child nodes. Tried with max depth option to some large number and removed uniqueness option but still the same results.

Comment: Are you sure nodes exist along `-[:CONNECTS]->` relationships beyond one level, and that they're of the `:Label2` label? Maybe you can add a screenshot of the relevant subgraph to your question if there's still confusion.

Comment: Great pick. It was the label2 which was failing; after I changed label2 to label1 and using one label for all the nodes it worked fine and returns the complete graph that I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Neo4j Graph Data Science](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/) algorithm [Breadth First Search](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/bfs/).

Following the guide above, first you create a [projected graph](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-create/) (basically it's the same graph that enables algorithm to run faster)

```sql
CALL gds.graph.create('myGraph', 'Node', 'REL', { relationshipProperties: 'cost' })
```

Then using the algorithm itself:

```sql
MATCH (a:Node{tag:'a'})
CALL gds.alpha.bfs.stream('myGraph', {startNode: id(a)})
YIELD path
RETURN path
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Just a note:
Apparently they've changed the routine name for projected graph creation
`CALL gds.graph.project('myGraph', 'Node', 'REL')`

https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-catalog-ops/